# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout while listening to meetup open_events streaming API

Tags: java, api, streaming, chunked-encoding, meetup

I am trying to listen to an endless stream from meetups open_events streaming API. For some reason I get a socketTimeoutException after (what seems to be) a random period of time. My code works for the meetups rsvps streaming API. I am using a okio.BufferedSource as you can see below. I get the exception for "while (!source.exhausted())", but when writing "while (true)" instead gives the exception on the line below. The difference between rsvps and open_events as far as I can see is that rsvps uses long polling and returns an array, and open_events uses chunked transfer encoding to maintain a persistent connection. Is the problem that I cannot use BufferedSource for chunked responses, and what should I then use instead?

```
    public static Observable<String> events(BufferedSource source) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            try {

                while (!source.exhausted()) {
                    subscriber.onNext(source.readUtf8Line());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    });
```

Full stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
at okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:207)
at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:71)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:64)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readHexadecimalUnsignedLong(RealBufferedSource.java:270)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1Codec.java:444)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:425)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
at  retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingRequestBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:285)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:60)
at com.example.meetup.MeetupListener$1.call(MeetupListener.java:123)
at com.example.meetup.MeetupListener$1.call(MeetupListener.java:118)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:250)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:147)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMap.java:74)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.onNext(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:53)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:505)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:463)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:246)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:147)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMap.java:74)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:146)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:125)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
... 37 more
Exception in thread "RxNewThreadScheduler-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:60)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: timeout
at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:386)
at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:383)
at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onError(ActionSubscriber.java:44)
at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:157)
at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:268)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:812)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:573)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:562)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:846)
at com.example.meetup.MeetupListener$1.call(MeetupListener.java:128)
at com.example.meetup.MeetupListener$1.call(MeetupListener.java:118)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:250)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:147)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMap.java:74)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.onNext(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:53)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:505)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:463)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:246)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:147)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMap.java:74)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:146)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:125)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8666)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
at okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:207)
at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:261)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:215)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:71)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:64)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readHexadecimalUnsignedLong(RealBufferedSource.java:270)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1Codec.java:444)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:425)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingRequestBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:285)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:60)
at com.example.meetup.MeetupListener$1.call(MeetupListener.java:123)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
... 37 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related but further down the error stack there is a mention of `Add onError handling`. Maybe you need to add this method to your implmentation?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately this solution didn't work.

Comment: I think I implemented onError incorrectly, could you provide any examples of how to do it correctly? I've tried to follow the link below, but could not get it to work: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Implementing-Your-Own-Operators

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with this API. My answer was solely based on reading the error stack trace.